# Change the entire CSS of my site

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, css

Environement: Foundation 2010

My question is simple : I want to change the entire CSS of my site, and **only my site**, not the others. I mean personalize all the content, like the ribbon and more.

I know we can add overriding CSS in webparts, but is there another way to do that "more properly" ?

NB: I'm not the central administrator of the Sharepoint Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing the site settings -> Look and Feel | Master Page -> CSS.  Make sure you leave the reset all sub sites box unchecked.  I'm a Site collection administrator for the site collection but you should be able to do this with full control or design permission.

Comment: This is a good way to do it, but there is a caveat.  Publishing features will need to be enabled on the site to be able to modify the Site/System Master Pages as well as the CSS file it references.

Comment: As Jordan said, Publishing features need to be enabled. [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89297/master-page-option-from-site-look-and-feel-is-missing) This post said that too. So, is there a way to do that without being the Site collection administrator ?

Comment: you can add a content editor web part and add a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to css">` tag on each page