# Inherit Site Master Page from parent of this site option is greyed out

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, css, html

From Site Settings page in Sharepoint Online, I am not able to select "Inherit Site Page from parent of this site" option as it is greyed out which is as follows

[image: Disbaled]

I'm very new to Sharepoint and I am not able to figure out on how to enable this button as I need to apply parent page css settings to its subsites.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a typical behavior when you're at the top site.

if you are in a sub site, go to site settings and you should see "go to top level site settings", meaning that you are in a site under the root site, and therefore can pick a different master page.

in your example, you can't inherit since you're already at the top

hope this helps

Comment: But how to go to site settings of Sub site. All I can see is Top site and there are 5 tabs which are the subsites of the top page. From the subsite (any of the tab), when I click on settings icon, I can only see "Shared with" and "Site Content". Please suggest

Comment: you don't have necessarily to go to a subsite to inherit the master page. you can go to the root site, click "reset all sites..." and confirm. all subsites will be set to inherit the master page. if you really want to specify a master page for a subsite, you can either use sharepoint designer, a script of some sort, or you will need to enable the publishing feature, which will make the option "Master Page" become visible at that site. see also, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89297/master-page-option-from-site-look-and-feel-is-missing

Comment: to go to site settings, click the gear icon, then site settings. it may vary depending on the version you're running. if you're struggling, you can try to open [site-url]/_layouts/15/settings.aspx. you might also be missing some permissions if you can't find your way there

Comment: For the Parent Site, I have used contoso.css as alternate css url. That is working for only Parent but not for its sub sites. Even though I have set the "Reset all subsites.." checkbox and saved the settings, sub sites' css didn't get updated. Is there any way to use contoso.css file as css file for subsites as well. I have this file placed in my Site Assets folder. Please suggest

Comment: check your browser console network tab. if the file is not there, re-do the alternate css inheritance checkbox. if it's there, check your url as you might be getting a 404. make sure you use a site collection relative url, e.g. /style library/xxx. I suggest style library over site assets

Comment: Many Thanks @Tiago. If possible, can you please help me with this one: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277231/sharepoint-site-map-to-be-displayed-on-sub-site-page/277233#277233