# sharepoint site map to be displayed on sub site page

Tags: site-collection, page-layout, navigation, site, site-settings

I have a parent site where I can see the site map navigation under menu bar which is as follows (highlighted in yellow)

[image: Navigation]

Now, when I go to sub sites, I cannot find this navigation map on the page. I need it like `Parent site > Sub site`. Being new to Sharepoint, I am in process of figuring out which settings will work for me. Can anyone please guide me on how to get this requirement done.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to start getting acquainted with the terms and what they mean

### global navigation

this is the navigation for the top area of your site.

your subsites can inherit the navigation from the parent site and it will look the same, while being managed at the top site

### current navigation

the current navigation, aka quick launch navigation, displays items that belong to the current site you are located in, placing them at the left area. you can inherit the setting, but typically each site will show its own items based on what lists exist in that site

### quick launch

quick launch is the control that displays items in the left area of each site. it is specific of each site.

### tree view

the tree view is another control, usually rendered below quick launch, that displays the current site's content in a sort of "tree" control with their icons, and expand/collapse function

this is also specific of each site

### other notes

you can enable and disable both quick launch and tree view on any site through "Navigation Elements" or by going to

/_layouts/15/navoptions.aspx

if you want to make a reusable left navigation, you can take advantage of Metadata Navigation using terms in a term set configured to be used for navigation

[image]

### same tree view on subsites

from what I understand, you want to make the treeview control display the same data on all sites and subsites (if you just want to enable it, see above and stop reading!)

although this is not the intended default behavior, it is possible through some tweaks as mentioned [here](http://dms.ecdcnet.europa.eu/Help/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx)

an example implementation would be:

1. create a new file under _catalogs\masterpage called seattle_custom.master (you can go to Files > Blank Master Page in SharePoint Designer).
2. copy the contents of seattle.master to it
3. locate SPHierarchyDataSourceControl and ensure you have this

> RootContextObject="" RootWebID="484c8c59-755d-4516-b8d2-1621b38262b4"

where the guid is the id of your root web.

to find the id of the root web, open the root web, open the browser console and type

> _spPageContextInfo.webId

4. save, check in and publish the master page file
5. pick the new master page under master page options to enable it and reset it for all sites

the tree view is now showing content from the point of view of the root web

please note that generally speaking we are advised against making master page changes, as they might cause issues when new updates are rolled out, but at least you're creating your own and not touching the ootb one

Answer (score -1):

Use **Managed Metadata Navigation** to achieve your goal.

this article can help you to understand:

[Managed Metadata Navigation In SharePoint Using Terms And Termsets](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/managed-metadata-navigation-in-sharepoint-using-terms-and-termsets/).

Comment: from the given link, i can see that by using managed metadata navigation, we can configure navigation on left and top of the page. But what i need is the navigation chain/map/site map (i don't know the exact term) to be displayed on the page similar to site settings > navigation (from the enclosed picture in my ques). Can you please suggest the route map on how to do so